# How to reduce latency when access new page in linux

Tags: c++, linux, caching, low-latency, tlb

The page size is 4KB in linux, but I access a new page, the latency is about twice large than inside a page. How can I reduce this latency?

Here is my test code. I use clock_gettime to measure the time cost in the main function.

```
#define MEM_SIZE 4096 * 12

long long GetRT() {
    struct timespec tp;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tp);
    return (long long) tp.tv_sec * 1000000000 + tp.tv_nsec;
}

void *InitSharedMemory() {
    int fd = shm_open("/test-steve", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, ACCESSPERMS);
    if (fd < 0) {
        perror("shm_open");
    }
    if (ftruncate(fd, MEM_SIZE) < 0) {
        perror("ftruncate");
    }
    void *mmap_ptr = mmap(NULL, MEM_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                          MAP_SHARED | MAP_POPULATE, fd, 0);

    if (mmap_ptr == (caddr_t)-1) {
        perror("mmap");
    }
    return mmap_ptr;
}

int main()
{
    constexpr auto STEP = 512;
    char arr[STEP];
    for (int i = 0; i < STEP; ++i) {
        arr[i] = i;
    }

    int ret = 0;
    void *buffer = InitSharedMemory();
    for (int i = 0; i < 40; ++i) {
        if ((i % 0x8) == 0) {
            // *(char *) buffer = 'a';
        }
        auto t1 = GetRT();
        *(char *) buffer = 'a';
        auto t2 = GetRT();
        ret += t2 - t1;
        printf("cost: %lld ns\n", t2 - t1);
        buffer  = (char *) buffer + STEP;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

The result is some like follows, is the extra latency TLB missing? how to avoid it?

```
cost: 272 ns
cost: 73 ns
cost: 76 ns
cost: 74 ns
cost: 74 ns
cost: 75 ns
cost: 73 ns
cost: 76 ns
cost: 281 ns
cost: 74 ns
cost: 73 ns
cost: 76 ns
cost: 76 ns
cost: 74 ns
cost: 73 ns
cost: 76 ns
cost: 334 ns
cost: 76 ns
cost: 76 ns
cost: 76 ns
cost: 76 ns
cost: 73 ns
cost: 76 ns
cost: 76 ns
cost: 267 ns
cost: 74 ns
cost: 74 ns
cost: 75 ns
cost: 73 ns
cost: 76 ns
cost: 73 ns
cost: 76 ns
cost: 260 ns
```

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid that you cannot avoid the cost of the first hit to a page (as illustrated by your example).

May be this cost could be amortised when using huge-pages (2MB) with `MAP_HUGETLB` in the flags of `mmap()`.

Depending on the applicative context, touching the first byte (or any) of each page once for all, right after the allocation, will force the commit (may be useful on numa hardware).
This will have a large initial cost but could lead to more predictable timings for the subsequent accesses.

Comment: use hughpage can solve. But I wonder why the first hit cost so many time? Is that minor page fault or TLB missing or something else?

Comment: I am not a specialist but I can't see anything else (page-fault + TLB miss).

Comment: +1 for an indeed lovely Profile motivation: "I'm **interested in understanding how programming languages, operating systems and hardware work**. Avoiding heavy code constructions, with many indirections and stacked layers of misunderstood APIs, appears to me like the minimal care one should take in order not to make computer programs waste too much energy." In recent days a more and more seldom professional dedication. ~RESPECT~ ( missing the InMOS days of smart networks with Transputers hardware supported parallel Occam-pi )